# Dialogflow: Regexp entity not matched

Tags: regex, dialogflow-es

I am going crazy with this problem, I am sure I am missing something...

I would like to match words that start with 2 characters or digits, followed by 1 or more character/digit/slash.

Some examples:

- AM9
- B9C
- AS/1
- *etc...*

So I have created an entity, let's say **EntityOne** as follows according to some RegExp tests (I have also tested the same regexp surrounded by "()", all tested on https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html that it seems to use re2):

[image]

and a test Intent with params defined as follows:

```
REQUIRED | PARAM NAME |    ENTITY  |  VALUE   | IS LIST | PROMPTS
   yes   |    name    | @EntityOne |  $value  |   no    | test:
```

And inside this intent I try with words similar to the examples above that should be matched.
But I see the prompt *"test:"* over and over, the entity is never matched.

Any hints please? Tell me if you want me to share additional info, but I think that there is nothing much to share. Thanks in advance

Comment: The regex is fine. Your setup must be failing.

Comment: thanks for your feedback @WiktorStribiżew, I will wait then for hints regarding a possible misconfiguration in my Intent/Entity. I have tried with a different entity and it works fine, this is why I am going totally crazy.. :)